# Allow active mixed content (iframes) with SSL and Content Security Policies

Tags: ssl, https, mixed-content

I've installed a `SSL` certificate on my server, and I've made it `HTTPS`. But I need to load existent iframes with embedded content, usually YouTube videos that were saved with `HTTP` url, but also other content that is not available via `HTTPS`.

`upgrade-insecure-requests` is not a suitable solution, since it blocks the passive content if it can't be retrieved with `HTTPS`, which without defining `Content-Security-Policy`is not blocked by browsers.

Which policy do I have to define to make the browser not block the active content?

Comment: Youtube is available via HTTPS, you know, right?

Comment: Yes, but I have other mixed content that is not available via HTTPS, which I also have to load.

Comment: CSP is about restricting the content compared to the default policy, not to loosen the  policy.

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable the mixed security check at site level. If browser would allow it, this behavior will provide a false sense of security and defeat the trust on the use of HTTPS.

Some browsers allow the setting to be disabled on per-installation basis. For example, you can disable the check in Firefox by changing the setting

```
security.mixed_content.block_active_content
```

in `about:config`.

Chrome doesn't allow it explicitly, and the only way is to click on [load anyway](http://du.screenstepslive.com/s/docs/m/7107/l/219447-allow-mixed-content-in-browsers). It is also worth to mention that newer versions of Chrome [no longer display a crossed padlock](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/10/chrome-finally-kills-off-the-http-https-mixed-content-warning/), instead Chrome will essentially downgrade the security of the page to HTTP if you load any HTTP content.

[image]